# Why does my virtualbox gateway duplicate SYN packets?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, tcp, port-forwarding, nat

I'm trying to set up port knocking using iptables on a Debian server hosted by VirtualBox on my Ubuntu machine. For some reason, when I knock on a port on the server from the host machine, this knock is duplicated several times by the virtual gateway which creates problems with the port knocking.

I've set up iptables on the guest server to log all incoming connections by

```
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG --log-prefix '*WALL Hit! '
```

in order to debug what is going on. The iptables logic seems to do its job, but I'm having trouble correctly knocking on the ports in sequence.

In the virtualbox settings I have port forwarded the ports used in the knocking-sequence in addition to the service port (22). When I try to "knock" on 9514 by doing

```
nmap -sT --host-timeout 201 --max-parallelism 1 --max-retries 0 -p 9514 localhost
```

`sudo tcpdump -i lo port 9514` on my host machine correctly produces the below result:

```
4:44:51.225394 IP localhost.37776 > localhost.9514: Flags [S], seq 3516530284, win 65495, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 586800892 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
14:44:51.225400 IP localhost.9514 > localhost.37776: Flags [S.], seq 2374911314, ack 3516530285, win 65483, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 586800892 ecr 586800892,nop,wscale 1], length 0
14:44:51.225406 IP localhost.37776 > localhost.9514: Flags [.], ack 1, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 586800892 ecr 586800892], length 0
14:44:51.225421 IP localhost.37776 > localhost.9514: Flags [R.], seq 1, ack 1, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 586800892 ecr 586800892], length 0
```

which shows that the host machine correctly did a TCP handshake with the VM server.

However, on my guest server I first correctly see a knock on the firewall produced by this initial handshake, but if I then wait for around 10 seconds, I see a repeated connection attempt, and then a third attempt and so on as shown in the iptables log:

```
Feb  9 14:44:51 uname kernel: [347106.973331] *WALL Hit! IN=enp0s3 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:08:00 SRC=10.0.2.2 DST=10.0.2.15 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=22453 PROTO=TCP SPT=37776 DPT=9514 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Feb  9 14:44:57 uname kernel: [347113.109626] *WALL Hit! IN=enp0s3 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:08:00 SRC=10.0.2.2 DST=10.0.2.15 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=22455 PROTO=TCP SPT=37776 DPT=9514 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Feb  9 14:45:09 uname kernel: [347125.126824] *WALL Hit! IN=enp0s3 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:08:00 SRC=10.0.2.2 DST=10.0.2.15 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=22457 PROTO=TCP SPT=37776 DPT=9514 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Feb  9 14:45:21 uname kernel: [347137.143457] *WALL Hit! IN=enp0s3 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:08:00 SRC=10.0.2.2 DST=10.0.2.15 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=22459 PROTO=TCP SPT=37776 DPT=9514 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Feb  9 14:45:33 uname kernel: [347149.159284] *WALL Hit! IN=enp0s3 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:08:00 SRC=10.0.2.2 DST=10.0.2.15 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=22461 PROTO=TCP SPT=37776 DPT=9514 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Feb  9 14:45:45 uname kernel: [347161.175126] *WALL Hit! IN=enp0s3 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:08:00 SRC=10.0.2.2 DST=10.0.2.15 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=22463 PROTO=TCP SPT=37776 DPT=9514 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0  
Feb  9 14:45:57 uname kernel: [347173.190381] *WALL Hit! IN=enp0s3 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:08:00 SRC=10.0.2.2 DST=10.0.2.15 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=22465 PROTO=TCP SPT=37776 DPT=9514 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

As you can see from the time-stamps, additional knocks are produced for some strange reason and these connection attempts do not show up on the `tcpdump` on the host machine.

However doing a `tcpdump` on the guest server shows lines like the following:

```
15:51:50.838919 IP 10.0.2.2.37792 > 10.0.2.15.9514: Flags [S], seq 1873367041, win 65535, options [mss 1460], length 0
```

corresponding to each duplicated SYN packet. This shows that the gateway, which is at the (virtual) ip 10.0.2.2 repeatedly sends syn packets to the guest server which is at the (virtual) ip 10.0.2.15.

This becomes a big problem when I try to set up port forwarding since then the additional knocks produced interfere with knocks to other ports. Does anyone know why this behavior happens and what I can do to limit the connection attempts to a single one?